# Can we check (see) who upvoted our question?

Tags: support

Can we see who voted our question's?

Comment: Haha, of course not!

Comment: Otherwise it will bring down-vote world war 1 ;)

Comment: LOL, actually the question was for downvote only, :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, you can not.  That would undermine the ability to vote without fear of retribution !

I would hope that in cases where someone downvotes, they would leave a comment - but we can't insist on this.

Comment: Even mods can't, if i am not wrong.

Comment: @AnkitSharma - no absolutely.  We have many powers to manage the site, but we can't see that.

Answer (score 0):

SE does keep track of votes. An example of this is reconciliation to correct REP when questions/answers are deleted or they close/merge accounts. Can this data not be found using the SE data queries tool? There are queries that some mods use to discover sock puppet accounts which includes looking up mass upvotes and/or the correlation of upvotes between two users.

I agree though, no one should know who up/down voted as it would just be bad for both the user and the community.